# Can't run the getting started with google app engine, maven and java

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy an application to google cloud.

I am following their tutorial at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/start?walkthrough_tutorial_id=java_gae_quickstart.

Which tells you to clone the repo  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-try-java and run the command "mvn appengine:run".
However when I do this I get the following error. 
Does anybody know how to resolve this?

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: Sep 17, 2019 10:03:56 AM com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader readConfigXml
[INFO] GCLOUD: SEVERE: Received exception processing /appengine-try-java/target/appengine-try-java-1.0/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] GCLOUD: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Received IOException parsing the input stream.
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.parseXml(XmlUtils.java:52)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.parseXml(XmlUtils.java:40)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.processXml(WebXmlReader.java:119)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.processXml(WebXmlReader.java:20)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.readConfigXml(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:89)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.readWebXml(WebXmlReader.java:96)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:191)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:416)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:157)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:99)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:85)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:354)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:301)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:383)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
[INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: java.sun.com
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)

[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.parseXml(XmlUtils.java:47)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  ... 21 more
[INFO] GCLOUD: 
[INFO] GCLOUD: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Invalid configuration
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.reportDeferredConfigurationException(DevAppServerImpl.java:443)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:236)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:223)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:404)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
[INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Received IOException parsing the input stream.
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.parseXml(XmlUtils.java:52)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.parseXml(XmlUtils.java:40)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.processXml(WebXmlReader.java:119)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.processXml(WebXmlReader.java:20)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AbstractConfigXmlReader.readConfigXml(AbstractConfigXmlReader.java:89)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.WebXmlReader.readWebXml(WebXmlReader.java:96)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.EarHelper.readWebModule(EarHelper.java:191)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager$WarModuleConfigurationHandle.readConfiguration(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:416)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.<init>(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:157)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:99)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApplicationConfigurationManager.newWarConfigurationManager(ApplicationConfigurationManager.java:85)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.<init>(DevAppServerImpl.java:146)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.doCreateDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:354)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerFactory.createDevAppServer(DevAppServerFactory.java:301)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:383)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  ... 3 more
[INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: java.sun.com
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:339)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:357)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1220)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:984)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:647)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1304)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.startDTDEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1270)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.setInputSource(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:264)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1161)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1045)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:959)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:842)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:771)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils.parseXml(XmlUtils.java:47)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  ... 21 more
```

Comment: The stacktrace you have provided does not contain any error, just info messages as the tag at the beginning of each row states ([INFO]). Could you please edit your question with the error you are talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably behind a proxy. If this is truth, unfortunately 
`com.google.apphosting.utils.config.XmlUtils` does not support variables like `HTTP_PROXY`, etc.

I had the same problem, so I did workaround. Solution can be:

1. Download:

   - http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd
   - http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd
2. Edit `web.xml` and use **absolute path** to downloaded files:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Oracle Corporation//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "[PATH_TO]/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app xmlns="[PATH_TO]/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    ...
</web-app>
```

3. Try run appengine again:

```
mvn appengine:run
```

This (not too beautiful) workaround works for me.